# Changing the name of the values in a column in R

Tags: r

I want to change in one vector the names of some variables that are *in* a column all at once. I know that I could do this with each single value in the dataset, but that would take hours.

I have this dataset:

```
df=data.frame(species = c("yo.manhereisareallllllylongname",
                       "heydude.this.is.realllylong",
                       "sooooooo.long",
                       "what.whatshouldIdo",
                       "what.whatshouldIdo",
                       "shouldIstayorshouldIgo",
                       "sooooooo.long"), 
           site = c("site1","site2","site3","site4","site5","site6","site7"))
```

Looks like this:

```
                          species  site
1 yo.manhereisareallllllylongname site1
2     heydude.this.is.realllylong site2
3                   sooooooo.long site3
4              what.whatshouldIdo site4
5              what.whatshouldIdo site5
6          shouldIstayorshouldIgo site6
7                   sooooooo.long site7
```

I want to create this vector (where you can see that I haven’t repeated the objects in the original dataset, they are unique.):

```
short_names=c("ymrln","heydude","slong","wwsid", "sisosig")
```

Which would correspond to this:

```
long_names=c("yo.manhereisareallllllylongname","heydude.this.is.realllylong","sooooooo.long","what.whatshouldIdo","shouldIstayorshouldIgo")
```

The final result is:

```
  species  site
1   ymrln site1
2 heydude site2
3   slong site3
4   wwsid site4
5   wwsid site5
6 sisosig site6
7   slong site7
```

Do you have a rapid way to do this? This is kind of a find and replace function in a dataset, not in the script.

Thanks,

Comment: One standard way: `short_names[ match(df$species, long_names) ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `mapvalues` function in the plyr package.

```
library(plyr)
df$species <- mapvalues(df$species, long_names, short_names)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `loopup` from `library(qdapTools)`.

```
 library(qdapTools)
 df$species <- lookup(df$species, data.frame(long_names, short_names))

df
#  species  site
#1   ymrln site1
#2 heydude site2
#3   slong site3
#4   wwsid site4
#5   wwsid site5
#6 sisosig site6
#7   slong site7
```

According to `?lookup`

> lookup-data.table based hash table useful for large vector lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
match_df <- data.frame(short_names, long_names)
df$species <- match_df$short_names[df2$species]

head(df)
# species  site
#1 sisosig site1
#2   ymrln site2
#3   slong site3
#4   wwsid site4
#5   wwsid site5
#6 heydude site6
```